# what is difference b/w @$_REQUEST[] and $_REQUEST[]

Tags: php

What is the difference between `@$_REQUEST[]`  and  `$_REQUEST[]`? Why do we use `@` in front of `$_REQUEST[]`?

Answer (score 0):

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

Please refer http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: $id=@$_REQUEST['id']; is it ignore error like undefined variable id if $_REQUEST['id'] returns null  ??

Comment: thanks .. in my log report so many these kind of errors are coming (undefined variable) so i can use $id=@$_REQUEST['id']; right OR $id= isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '';
 which is better ???

Comment: Please use second one..

Answer (score 0):

@$_REQUEST[] - using [@](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)(error control operator) to hide errors

[$_REQUEST[]](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)  - HTTP Request variables